# Two key codes at once

Tags: javascript, key

I am making a very simple game in Javascript. The games requires two objects to be moved at the same time by different keys. I have tried other ways to use two keycodes at once but they have not worked. They also need to keep moving, not just move once. Any help?

Comment: Not possible in a rational way (except some special keys). Use an object/array to store directions from keydowns and keyups.

Comment: Check my answer and working demo and tell me if you need something different.

Answer (score 1):

See my demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/mulperi/oh7n3Lx9/
It shows how to make two class-based players and control them both individually at the same time.

I hope this helps you!

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>World's BEstest Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; color: hotpink; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px pink">Player Movement 2.0</h1>
    <p>Class based player objects and keyboard controls</p>
    <p>Use the arrow and WASD keys to move your balls</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black; border-radius: 5px;">

    </canvas>
    <script>
      const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

      let settings = {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        speed: 1
      };

      c.width = settings.width;
      c.height = settings.height;

      /*
        Object holding boolean values for every keypress
      */
      let keyPresses = {};

      function listenKeyboard() {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
      };

      const keyUp = e => {
        keyPresses[e.key] = false;
      };

      const keyDown = e => {
        // console.log(e.key)
        keyPresses[e.key] = true;
      };



      class Player {

        constructor(x, y, color, left, right, up, down, radius) {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.color = color;
          this.left = left;
          this.right = right;
          this.up = up;
          this.down = down;
          this.radius = radius;
        }

        draw() {
          ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
        }

        update() {
          if (keyPresses[this.left]) {
            this.x -= settings.speed;
          }
          if (keyPresses[this.right]) {
            this.x += settings.speed;
          }
          if (keyPresses[this.up]) {
            this.y -= settings.speed;
          }
          if (keyPresses[this.down]) {
            this.y += settings.speed;
          }

                    // Screen bounds
          if (this.x < 0 + this.radius) this.x = 0 + this.radius;
          if (this.y < 0 + this.radius) this.y = 0 + this.radius;
          if (this.x > settings.width - this.radius) this.x = settings.width - this.radius;
          if (this.y > settings.height - this.radius) this.y = settings.width - this.radius;
        }

      }

      /*
          Creating the player objects
      */
      let p1 = new Player(25, 25, "red", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", 10);
      let p2 = new Player(75, 75, "black", "a", "d", "w", "s", 5);

      function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, settings.width, settings.height);
        p1.draw();
        p2.draw();
      };

      function update() {
        draw();
        listenKeyboard();
        p1.update();
        p2.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      };

      requestAnimationFrame(update);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```